# How to transfer a Jenkins job from one Cloudbees to another Cloudbees?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

When Jenkins is hosted on local computers, and you need to transfer jobs from one computer to another, you simply go into the Jenkins folder structure, copy the XML file, and paste it in the new computer's folder structure.

How to do transfer a Jenkins job from one Cloudbees to another Cloudbees?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Job Import Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Job+Import+Plugin) to achieve it.